# surnames in small cap with nameauth package

Tags: indexing, small-caps, nameauth

I use now the `\package{nameauth}`.

I just want to have the same form of names presentation in my work (the first & the other) with **only the surname or mononym in small capitals** in my text & in my index. I can read the basic arguments here of the package here :

[image]

My aim seems simple when you know programming like in the *man* "2.5.5. custom formatting", but I'm not a good programmer. Here the exemple in the *man* :

[image]
[image]

In my work, I'm using `arara` `xelatex` `imakeidx` `xindy` `glossaries` `babel` & for exemple :

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = arara   
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[noformat]{nameauth}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\Name[Jean de]{La Fontaine}, \\
\Name*[Jean de]{La Fontaine}, \\
\FName[Jean de]{La Fontaine}[Jean] \\
\AKA[Jean de]{La Fontaine}{le fabuleux}\\

Jean de \textsc{La Fontaine} \\ % to show you what I want…

\printindex
\end{document}
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex: {shell: yes}
```

You can see the result :

[image]

And, this is the index :

[image]

If you mean it's possible (nothing is impossible, isn't it ?), help me please.

Comment: Could you add a minimal example of code?

Comment: @egreg Of course

Comment: What do you mean by 'If you mean it's possible... hand me please.'?

Comment: To what extent do you actually use the facilities of `nameauth`? Because it seems to me that the package is absolutely not designed to allow what you want. I think you will need to redefine `\Name`. I could be wrong as I only looked quickly, but essentially `\NamesFormat` seems to be applied to the whole name, whatever it is, and takes a single argument. To break that up, I suspect you need to start breaking up the main functions of the package.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your attention. You're right for your observation, grayshade worked in this way, thank you. So sorry for my bad english, I meant help, not hand :s  Bye

Comment: I updated my answer below to be current for version 3.2 of nameauth. The package documentation goes into considerable detail as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to your suggestion the `\NameFormat` is not of any help here since it does always affect the whole name and does not allow formatting of just the surname.

And since the `nameauth` package buries all its functionality within the definition of the `Name` command - including the indexing etc - it does not allow easy modifications of the type you asked for. But with tweaking quite a bit of the code of the package, I believe I have come up with a modified version that allows doing what you ask for.

I introduce two new features to the package:

1. Similar to the `\CapName` command now there's a `\SCapName` command which puts the surname into small caps for the current name and also lists it in the index with the surname in small caps.
2. Quite possibly more interesting for you is the new package option `namesmallcaps` which - similar to the `allcaps` option - always sets the surname in small caps, but contrary to the `allcaps` option also indexes them in small caps. (Note from [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nameauth/nameauth.pdf) on the `allcaps` option: 'Note that this only affects the printed form; no capitalization occurs in the index. In that case, the user should type in the caps manually.' Thus here the behavious of the new `smallcaps` and existing `allcaps` option differ!)

Now, finally some code:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = arara   
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[noformat,namesmallcaps]{nameauth_mod}
\makeindex

\usepackage{showidx}

\begin{nameauth}
    \< LaFontaine & Jean de & La Fontaine & >
\end{nameauth}
\SubvertName[Jean de]{La Fontaine}

\begin{document}
\Name[Jean de]{La Fontaine} \emph{and} \LaFontaine

\Name*[Jean de]{La Fontaine}{} \emph{and} \LLaFontaine

\FName[Jean de]{La Fontaine}[Jean] \emph{and} \SLaFontaine %\S* seems not quite the same as \FName

\CapName\Name[Jean de]{La Fontaine}{} \emph{and} \CapName\LaFontaine

\SCapName\Name[Jean de]{La Fontaine}{} \emph{and} \SCapName\LaFontaine

\AKA[Jean de]{La Fontaine}{le fabuleux}


Jean de \textsc{La Fontaine} % to show you what I want…

\printindex
\end{document}
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex: {shell: yes}
```

Produces:

[image]
where the right hand side shows the index key (note the use of [the `showidx` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/makeindx.pdf)).

Similarly, when not using the `namesmallcaps` option, the other formatting options remain intact (including the index) and the output would be:

[image]
where only the two uses with `\SCapName` are in small caps, including the index entries.

Finally, the code of the modified package is [here](http://pastebin.com/92yhzS4E) - put it into `nameauth_mod.sty` in the same folder you're working in and replace `\usepackage{nameauth}` by `\usepackage{nameauth_mod}`.

A diff between the original and the new .sty looks like this:

```
24c24
< \ProvidesPackage{nameauth}
---
> \ProvidesPackage{nameauth_mod}
37a38,39
> \newif\if@nameauth@SmallCaps
> \newif\if@nameauth@SmallThis
50a53
> \DeclareOption{namesmallcaps}{\@nameauth@SmallCapstrue}
82a86,89
> \newcommand*{\@nameauth@SmallCapRoot}[1]%
> {%
>   \textsc{\@nameauth@Root{#1}}%
> }
142a150,153
> \newcommand{\SCapName}%
> {%
>   \@nameauth@SmallThistrue%
> }
162a174
>   \if@nameauth@SmallCaps\SCapName\fi%
173c185,191
<   \let\IndexShort\RawShort%
---
>   \protected@edef\SmallCapShort{\@nameauth@SmallCapRoot{#2}}%
>   \if@nameauth@SmallThis%
>     \protected@edef\RawShortIdx{\textsc{\RawShort}}%
>   \else%
>     \protected@edef\RawShortIdx{\RawShort}%
>   \fi%
>   \let\IndexShort\RawShortIdx%
176c194
<     \let\IndexSurnames\RawShort%
---
>     \let\IndexSurnames\RawShortIdx%
189a208,212
>     \if@nameauth@SmallThis%
>       \let\Reversed\SmallCapShort%
>       \let\Surnames\SmallCapShort%
>       \let\PrintShort\SmallCapShort%
>     \fi%
192c215
<     \protected@edef\IndexSurnames{\RawShort\Space\Suffix}%
---
>     \protected@edef\IndexSurnames{\RawShortIdx\Space\Suffix}%
217a241,249
>     \if@nameauth@SmallThis%
>       \protected@edef\Reversed{\Suffix\Space\SmallCapShort}%
>       \protected@edef\Surnames{\SmallCapShort\Space\Suffix}%
>       \if@nameauth@RevThis%
>         \let\PrintShort\Suffix%
>       \else%
>         \let\PrintShort\SmallCapShort%
>       \fi%
>     \fi%
220a253
>   \@nameauth@SmallThisfalse%
```

Comment: A big big thanks for your solution. I'll try it right now. Hope this may help other.

Comment: Ok, it run perfectly ! Again thank you. I don't know how, but you should propose the modification to the nameauth package author Charles P. Schaum !

Comment: Happy to help. If you do later on find any errors - let me know.

Comment: @grayshade I use now your first option. I'll try later with AKA & PName…

Comment: @grayshade Hello, I use every day your package. Another question : is it possible to give the same treatment to the fourth argument of `\AKA[#1]{#2}[#3]{#4}[#5]` in the package ? Maybe, if it's difficult, I open another question page… Thanks

Comment: @Zouib sorry for the late reply, things were a bit busy here - I've seen [your new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199343/first-occurrence-of-name-with-or-without-forename-in-nameauth-package) and provided a reply there.

Comment: Merci for your help

Comment: @grayshade Hi. I abuse your help after a few months, so I continue to use your package, and I think there are still some trouble:
1. the `\AKA[#1]{#2}[#3]{#4}[#5]` don't index `#2` in smallcaps
2. the `\IndexName[#1]{#2}` either.
Unfortunately I don't understand the package code... If you can still help me once again! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that current versions of the package probably will not work with the diff above. Version 2.2 will be current as of early December 2015.

[Edit for 2017, with many changes below] Version 3.2 is current as of April 2017 and has even more features to aid this kind of formatting.

Fortunately, since you want to have everything formatted in both the body text *and* in the index, there is a way to do that without typing a lot of extra macros:

```
\PretagName[Jean de]{\textSC{La Fontaine}}{La Fontaine, Jean de}
\begin{nameauth}
  \< Fontaine & Jean de & \textSC{La Fontaine} & >
\end{nameauth}
\Fontaine
\LFontaine
\SFontaine[Jean]
```

Please use the `altformat` package option if your entire document has Continental formatting. That way, `\CapThis` will not cause errors. If you do use `\CapThis` you will need to use `\noexpand` as well, e.g.,:

```
\PretagName[Hernando]{\noexpand\textSC{\noexpand\AltCaps{d}e Soto}}{de Soto, Hernando}
\begin{nameauth}
  \< Soto & Hernando & \noexpand\textSC{\noexpand\AltCaps{d}e Soto} & >
\end{nameauth}
\Soto
\CapThis\Soto
```

The issue with "surnames" here is that a surname field (SNN) can be divided into a radix/suffix pair. What that pair means is context-sensitive.

1. In Western names, you would want both radix and suffix formatted. Here the radix and suffix belong properly to the surname. You would format them according to your needs as:

   ```
   \PretagName[Thurston]{\textSC{Howell},\textSC{III}}{Howell, Thurston 3}
   \Name[Thurston]{\textSC{Howell},\textSC{III}}
   ```

   If you try to put the whole surname and suffix within one scope of `\textSC` you will likely create an error of unbalanced braces.
2. In Eastern names, for which full capitalization is implemented, you want only the root formatted. Thus:

   ```
   \PretagName{\textSC{Sun}, Yat-sen}{Sun Yat-sen}
   \Name{\textSC{Sun}, Yat-sen}
   ```
3. In ancient or medieval names it could go either way, as references to Thomas Aquinas and Thomas à Kempis suggest. However, it is likely that for royal names, again you probably want both root and suffix formatted:

   ```
   \PretagName{\textSC{Elizabeth},\textSC{I}}{Elizabeth I}
   \Name{\textSC{Elizabeth},\textSC{I}}
   ```

There is no automatic way to tell what is a "surname" when you generalize the matter of a name. This is a design feature because the nameauth package tries not to have any ethnocentric bias.

The current package documentation goes into considerable depth regarding these and other related issues.