# first occurrence of Name with or without forename in nameauth package

Tags: indexing, small-caps, nameauth

I ask [this question about `nameauth` package format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194981/surnames-in-small-cap-with-nameauth-package) last month. You can see there my configuration who didn't change. I use the good solution of @greyshade but I have now to other problems with `nameauth` package :

1. I write interviews transcripts, & sometime speakers quote a name for the first time without forename, & after both : exemple "My name is Bond, James Bond". Is it possible to reference first occurrence like no-starred option `\Name[<James>]{<Bond>}` -> Bond ? So, I just want to use the starred & no-starred option in the first occurrence like other occurrences. So, same comportment for first occurrence & other.
2. I use some complex names, like princes or artists with pseudonym. With the solution of @greyshade [you can find there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194981/surnames-in-small-cap-with-nameauth-package), I put all surname in small caps. Is it possible to give the same treatment to the fourth argument of `\AKA[#1]{#2}[#3]{#4}[#5]` ?

Thanks for your help.

My config :

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = arara   
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[noformat,namesmallcaps]{nameauth_mod}
\makeindex

\usepackage{showidx}

\begin{document}
My name is \Name[James]{Bond}, \Name*[James]{Bond}. 

My name is \textsc{Bond}, James \textsc{Bond}.

I'm \AKA[Freda Joséphine]{McDonald}[Joséphine]{Baker}.

I'm Joséphine \textsc{Baker}.

\printindex
\end{document}
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex: {shell: yes}
```

> the code of the modified package is [here](http://pastebin.com/92yhzS4E) - put it into `nameauth_mod.sty` in the same folder you're working in and replace `\usepackage{nameauth}` by `\usepackage{nameauth_mod}`

Comment: @greyshade I just want the same comportment for first occurrence & other : unstarred command `\Name[Forename]{Name}` print a `Name`; starred command `\Name[Forename]{Name}` print a `Forename Name`. No différence between first occurrence & other occurrences. An idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm not quite sure what you want with your question - can you elaborate a bit? How would those commands work in the remainder of the text in your vision?
2. I believe I managed to give the same treatment to `#4` of `AKA` - but please do test it thoroughly before relying on it. It seems like the package author himself did not consider `AKA` when implementing the `allcaps` option (i.e. running your MWE with `\usepackage[noformat,allcaps]{nameauth}` does not captialise the `Baker` of `\AKA[Freda Joséphine]{McDonald}[Joséphine]{Baker}`..)..

   The updated code is in a [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9JKjwnZf) again.

Comment: Great ! Your solution for my second question run very good ! (sorry for my absence, I was working without network for a week). I try to clarify my first one.

Comment: I valid your answer… Do you think that I must isolate my first question in another post ?

Comment: @Zouib sorry, quite busy here.. a quick look at [the manual](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nameauth/nameauth.pdf) suggests `\SubvertName` (see p. 17, section 2.5.7) may offer an immediate 'workaround' for your problem. If this occurs often, a fix may be possible by fiddling with the package code some more - if that's desired, please split it into a new question and leave a comment with @greyshade so I'll be aware and I may have a look some time towards the end of the week..

Comment: It works, a little bit time consuming, but it prints what I want. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Edit for 2017, nameauth v3.2] Not only are there extensive features available in the package for manipulating format and name forms, but the latest version has documentation that explains this in great detail.

You likely want to use `\SubvertName` and the formatting described in my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194981/surnames-in-small-cap-with-nameauth-package), You could do something like:

```
\PretagName[James]{\textsc{Bond}}{Bond, James}
My name is \SubvertName[James]{\textSC{Bond}}\Name[James]{\textSC{Bond}},%
\ \Name*[James]{\textSC{Bond}}
```